# Set read mail as unread if they don't have category assigned

Tags: email, script, microsoft-outlook-2016, rules

Is there anyway to make Outlook set the read email that doesn't have any categories assigned to them back to unread?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```vb
Public Sub Mark_Unread_If_No_Category()

    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace: Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Dim Item As Object

    For Each Item In olFolder.Items
        If Item.Class = 43 Then  ' 43 = an email
            Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem: Set oMail = Item
            If oMail.Categories = "" Then
                Debug.Print "Marking as unread: " & oMail.Subject
                oMail.UnRead = True
                oMail.Save
            End If
            Set oMail = Nothing
        End If
        DoEvents  ' So Outlook doesn't lock up whilst running
    Next

    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing

End Sub
```

I know that it correctly looks in the inbox and it correctly finds emails without categories (the `Debug.Print` confirms this) however I've not checked that those emails become unread.

As a result, you should backup your inbox before you give this a go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how do you set it to just do it on one specific folder or inbox ?

Comment: Assuming your folder (say "TPS Reports") sits within your inbox, then you should change `objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` to `objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("TPS Reports")`

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy. Just create a Custom **Search Folder**, name it as you like (say, "Not categorized") select required folder(s), specify the **Criteria** on the **Advanced** tab as follows:

Field: **All Mail Fields -> Categories**
Condition: **is empty**

Click **Add to List** and then OK, OK.

Now you can select all messages in this folder and mark them all as Unread.